# Cannot sign in using Firefox

Tags: support, login

Firefox 31.0

1. go to www.stackoverflow.com
2. Press the log in button on top bar
3. Shows the list of options to sign in.
4. Select "Log in with google"
5. 2 sec later a top banner comes with welcome message.and redirect link

But it doesn't change the top bar to actual logged in condition. It remains the same as not logged in. The redirect also didn't do anything.

Note: Log in with FB also pointing to the same issue.

I'm using OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)

Comment: Have you tried starting Firefox in [Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)?

Comment: the same problem am facing. i just shifted to chrome

Answer (score 3):

Clear your cookies (for the Q&A site as well as stackauth.com), cache, and if that doesn't do it (oddly enough) browser history.

Comment: sorry doesn't help

Comment: Just wanted to report that this did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and select what you want to delete and hit OK
Restart Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Press `CTRL`+<kbd>F5</kbd> together to refresh browser caches and reopen stackoverflow.